# Where has Processing output file gone?

Tags: file, save, missing-data

I am learning to use the Processing programming language and want to save data in a file. For a start, to get the feel of it, I tried the code below, taken from the Processing [Reference for "close()"](https://www.processing.org/reference/PrintWriter_close_.html). It runs ok but I can find no trace of the file "positions.txt". Please, what has gone wrong? Am I looking for it in the wrong place, including `~/sketchbook`, or have I made some other obvious error?

```
PrintWriter output;

void setup() {
  // Create a new file in the sketch directory
  output = createWriter("positions.txt"); 
}

void draw() {
  point(mouseX, mouseY);
  output.println(mouseX);  // Write the coordinate to the file
}

void keyPressed() {
  output.flush();  // Writes the remaining data to the file
  output.close();  // Finishes the file
  exit();  // Stops the program
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the file at:

/home/Harry/sketchbook/outputfiletest/positions.txt

I saved the program as "outputfiletest"

The entry for "createWriter" to this say "Creates a new file in the sketch folder, and a PrintWriter object to write to it." In fact it creates the file in the folder for the sketch inside the sketchbook folder.

Should have looked deeper before asking, sorry.

I have now solved all the problems I had, and can open a file in my home directory instead of the default. The other issues were simply my programming errors.